# Android ListView Animation weird behavior

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I want to animate onFling events on my list view.

The animation works fine, but at the wrong row.

For example:

1. ListView with only one item, the animation work as expected.
2. ListView with two items: with the gesture is make on the first item the second one is animated and vice-versa.
3. ListView with three items: with the gesture is make on the first item se last one is animated , on the second item the second item is animated (as expected), on the last item the first item is animated.

**CODE:**

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    int position = listView.pointToPosition(Math.round(e1.getX()),
            Math.round(e1.getY()));
    View row = listView.getChildAt(position);
    TranslateAnimation anim = null;
    if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH || row == null)
        return true;
    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0);
        this.handleSwipe.onHandleSwipeLeft(position);
    } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
        anim = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,-1,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0);
        this.handleSwipe.onHandleSwipeRight(position);
    }else{
        return true;
    }

    anim.setDuration(500);
    row.startAnimation(anim);
    return true;
}
```

**OBS:**

Already debug, and the position and row are always right.

I'm using api level 7.

The code work fine on android 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Guilherme, probably the code:

```
    int position = listView.pointToPosition(Math.round(e1.getX()),
        Math.round(e1.getY()));
```

Isn't returning the row id 3. Can you confirm that?

Comment: As i said, no! There are returning the expected value. I'm almost certain this is an android BUG. On api >= 11 this code work fine.